# How do I stop the timeout from a function recursively when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, project, clock

I'm building a simple digital clock on JavaScript and have implemented the 12 hour format clock as follows:

```
function get12hrTime()
{
      
      var date=new Date();
      var hh=date.getHours();
      var mm=date.getMinutes();
      var ss=date.getSeconds();
      var session="AM";
      if(hh==0)
      {
            hh=12;
      }
      if(hh>12)
      {
            hh=hh-12;
            session = "PM";
      }
      hh=(hh<10)? "0" + hh : hh;
      mm=(mm<10)? "0" + mm : mm;
      ss=(ss<10)? "0" + ss : ss;

      let time = hh + "." + mm + "." + ss + " "+session;
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;
      let t1=setTimeout(function(){
            get12hrTime()
      },1000);
}
```

I'm calling this via an onclick function. Now I'm trying to implement a format switcher for 24hr format as :

```
function get24hrTime()
{
      
      var date=new Date();
      var hh=date.getHours();
      var mm=date.getMinutes();
      var ss=date.getSeconds();
      var session="AM";
      
      if(hh>12)
      {
            session = "PM";
      }
      hh=(hh<10)? "0" + hh : hh;
      mm=(mm<10)? "0" + mm : mm;
      ss=(ss<10)? "0" + ss : ss;

      let time = hh + "." + mm + "." + ss + " "+session;
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;
      let t2=setTimeout(function(){
            get24hrTime()
      },1000);
}
```

The issue is that the timeouts are not syncing and if I use the switcher after I get the 12hr time the time keeps switching between 12hr and 24hr.

I tried using clearTimeout but couldnt find a way to do so. I could always use 2 buttons for 12hr and 24hr but I want a switcher. Is there a way to stop the timeout in the other function in the 24hr function?

Comment: Why would you need two different timeouts for this to begin with? All you want to do, is change how the timer value gets displayed. So this can easily be just _one_ function, that accesses a variable in an outside scope to determine, which format it should currently display.

Comment: _Is there a way to stop the timeout in the other function in the 24hr function?_. Yes, use `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

If the `t1` and `t2` variables are in a higher scope, both functions can access them and clear them.  For example:

```
let t1;
let t2;

function get12hrTime() {
  //...

  if (t2) {
    clearTimeout(t2);
  }
  t1 = setTimeout(function() {
    get12hrTime()
  }, 1000);
}

function get24hrTime() {
  //...

  if (t1) {
    clearTimeout(t1);
  }
  t2 = setTimeout(function() {
    get24hrTime()
  }, 1000);
}
```

This way each "clock" always clears any existing timeout for the other "clock" before setting its own.

Comment: I see yeah that works. Cool thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `t1` and `t2` to the higher scope

I also removed from duplicates from your code:

```js
function get12hrTime() {

  var date = new Date();
  var hh = date.getHours();
  var mm = date.getMinutes();
  var ss = date.getSeconds();
  var session = "AM";
  if (hh == 0) {
    hh = 12;
  }
  if (hh > 12) {
    hh = hh - 12;
    session = "PM";
  }
  hh = (hh < 10) ? "0" + hh : hh;
  mm = (mm < 10) ? "0" + mm : mm;
  ss = (ss < 10) ? "0" + ss : ss;

  return hh + "." + mm + "." + ss + " " + session;

}

function get24hrTime() {

  var date = new Date();
  var hh = date.getHours();
  var mm = date.getMinutes();
  var ss = date.getSeconds();
  var session = "AM";

  if (hh > 12) {
    session = "PM";
  }
  hh = (hh < 10) ? "0" + hh : hh;
  mm = (mm < 10) ? "0" + mm : mm;
  ss = (ss < 10) ? "0" + ss : ss;

  return hh + "." + mm + "." + ss + " " + session;

}

let timeout;

function loop(fn) {
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = fn();
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    loop(fn)
  }, 1000);
}
let h24 = true
loop(get24hrTime)
btn.onclick = () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout)
  h24 = !h24
  loop(h24 ? get24hrTime : get12hrTime)
}
```

```html
<p id="time"></p>
<button id="btn">change</button>
```